# PHP. Поиск по массиву

Tags: php

Имеется массив городов, нужно сделать множественный поиск по этому массиву.

```
$cities = [
'0a83d21d-11e5' => "Бабаи",
'0a83d21d-11e5' => "Бабаи1",
'0a83d21d-11e5' => "Бабаи22",
'0a83d21d-11e5' => "Бабаи33",
'0b9a89db-11e4' => "Зеленогорское",
'0befc300-11e4' => "Владимировка (Донецкая обл.)",
'0c4d5128-11e3' => "Берегомет",
'0c29a594-11e4' => "Карнауховка(Днепропетровская обл.)",
'0cbfcfd7-11e4' => "Богдановка (Кировоградская обл.)",
'0ccbf4b5-11e5' => "Ромодан",
'0d9256d1-11e5' => "Скороходово (Полтавська обл.)",
'0db17b0a-11de' => "Корюковка",
'0db17b0c-11de' => "Сосница"
]
```

допустим приходит ajax-запрос с таким словом `Баб`, нужно чтобы результат был таким:

```
$cities = [
'0a83d21d-11e5' => "Бабаи",
'0a83d21d-11e5' => "Бабаи1",
'0a83d21d-11e5' => "Бабаи22",
'0a83d21d-11e5' => "Бабаи33",
]
```

Подскажите, как сделать такой поиск в массиве?
т.е. интересует сам поиск по массиву, код php, ajax это как пример привёл

Comment: проблема то в чем ваша?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так, можно использовать регулярку.

```
$input = "Баб";
$cities = [
'0a83d21d-11e5' => "Бабаи",
'0a83d21d-11e5' => "Бабаи1",
'0a83d21d-11e5' => "Бабаи22",
'0a83d21d-11e5' => "Бабаи33",
'0b9a89db-11e4' => "Зеленогорское",
'0befc300-11e4' => "Владимировка (Донецкая обл.)",
'0c4d5128-11e3' => "Берегомет",
'0c29a594-11e4' => "Карнауховка(Днепропетровская обл.)",
'0cbfcfd7-11e4' => "Богдановка (Кировоградская обл.)",
'0ccbf4b5-11e5' => "Ромодан",
'0d9256d1-11e5' => "Скороходово (Полтавська обл.)",
'0db17b0a-11de' => "Корюковка",
'0db17b0c-11de' => "Сосница"
]
$pattern = "/".$input."/uism";
$output = null;
foreach ($cities as $k => $city)
   if (preg_match($pattern, $city) > 0)
       $output[$k] = $city;
```

Либо, чтобы работало быстрее используйте функцию substr вместо регулярных выражений

Comment: `preg_filter()` для  этих целей есть, или `array_filter()`

Comment: Не лучше ли тогда использовать preg_grep вместо перебора в цикле? с Вашим шаблоном это будет `$output = preg_grep("/$input/uism", $cities);`

Comment: @Peresada результат - `array ( '0a83d21d-11e5' => 'Бабаи33', )`

Comment: как это правильно сделать?

Comment: @word, ошибка не в решении а в изначальном условии - у Вас 4 элемента массива с повторяющимся ключом, при определении массива предыдущие элементы просто затираются.

Comment: благодарю всех за решения